# Extract method in C# to use throughout project

Tags: c#, oop, methods

Forgive the lengthy code here, and I also realise this may be a very basic fundamental question for any object-oriented developer, but I'm a front-end developer in at the deep end with .NET and trying to learn about classes and methods with an actual example.  I've read resources to explain this stuff but immediately get stuck with the complexities of real-world code.

Basically I have a bunch of methods for adding comments to a web page and manipulating the status (marking as spam, deleting etc).  Many of these methods call an 'EmailNotification' method, which sends an email to an administrator at each stage.  It works great.

However, I'd like to use the 'EmailNotification' method elsewhere in the project, calling it from a different .cs file.  When I try to do this it doesn't recognise the method because (I think!?) it's not a public static method.

Can anyone explain to me how to extract the EmailNotification method so that I can use it in different places around the code?  I have tried creating a new class with this method inside it, but I just can't get it to work.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace UComment.Domain
{
public class Comment
{
    public delegate void CommentCreatedEventHandler(Comment sender, EventArgs e);
    public delegate void CommentDeletedEventHandler(Comment sender, EventArgs e);
    public delegate void CommentSpamEventHandler(Comment sender, EventArgs e);
    public delegate void CommentApprovedEventHandler(Comment sender, EventArgs e);

    public static event CommentCreatedEventHandler CommentCreated;
    public static event CommentDeletedEventHandler CommentDeleted;
    public static event CommentSpamEventHandler CommentSpam;
    public static event CommentApprovedEventHandler CommentApproved;

    protected virtual void OnCommentCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CommentCreated != null) CommentCreated(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnCommentSpam(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CommentSpam != null) CommentSpam(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnCommentApproved(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CommentApproved != null) CommentApproved(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnCommentDelete(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CommentDeleted != null) CommentDeleted(this, e);
    }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentNodeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public bool Spam { get; set; }
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CommenText { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public Comment(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        var sqlHelper = DataLayerHelper.CreateSqlHelper(cms.GlobalSettings.DbDSN);
        var reader = sqlHelper.ExecuteReader("select * from Comment where id = @id",
                                             sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@id", id));

        if(!reader.HasRecords) throw new Exception(string.Format("Comment with id {0} was not found", id));

        reader.Read();

        Name = reader.GetString("name");
        ParentNodeId = reader.GetInt("nodeid");
        Email = reader.GetString("email");
        Website = reader.GetString("website");
        Approved = reader.GetBoolean("approved");
        Spam = reader.GetBoolean("Spam");
        Created = reader.GetDateTime("created");
        CommenText = reader.GetString("comment");
        StatusId = reader.GetInt("statusid");
    }

    private Comment()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set as approved, mark as Not Spam - ignore HAM status
    /// </summary>
    public void MarkAsApproved()
    {
        var sqlHelper = DataLayerHelper.CreateSqlHelper(cms.GlobalSettings.DbDSN);
        sqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(
             "update comment set approved = 1, spam = 0, statusid = 2 where id = @id",
             sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@id", Id));

        OnCommentApproved(EventArgs.Empty);

        // Send approval email
        EmailNotification(1);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove approval status. Ignore Spam and Ham states
    /// </summary>
    public void MarkAsNotApproved()
    {
        var sqlHelper = DataLayerHelper.CreateSqlHelper(cms.GlobalSettings.DbDSN);
        sqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(
             "update comment set approved = 0, statusid = 3 where id = @id",
             sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@id", Id));

        OnCommentApproved(EventArgs.Empty);

        // Send rejection email
        EmailNotification(2);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Spam cannot be ham or approved
    /// </summary>
    public void MarkAsSpam()
    {
        var sqlHelper = DataLayerHelper.CreateSqlHelper(cms.GlobalSettings.DbDSN);
        sqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(
             "update comment set spam = 1, ham = 0, approved = 0, statusid = 3 where id = @id",
             sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@id", Id));

        OnCommentSpam(EventArgs.Empty);

        // No email notification required - spammer not worthy of a reason for rejection
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Ham is "not spam" - approved comments from Akismet. 
    /// </summary>
    public void MarkAsHam()
    {
        var sqlHelper = DataLayerHelper.CreateSqlHelper(cms.GlobalSettings.DbDSN);
        sqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(
           "update comment set spam = 0, ham = 1 where id = @id",
           sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@id", Id));

        // No email notification required, simply marking spam as ham
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        if (Id < 1) return;

        var sqlHelper = DataLayerHelper.CreateSqlHelper(cms.GlobalSettings.DbDSN);
        sqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("delete from comment where id = @id", sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@id", Id));

        Id = -1;
        OnCommentDelete(EventArgs.Empty);

        // Permanent deletion
    }

    public void Reject()
    {
        if (Id < 1) return;

        var sqlHelper = DataLayerHelper.CreateSqlHelper(cms.GlobalSettings.DbDSN);
        sqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("update comment set statusid = 3 where id = @id", sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@id", Id));

        //Id = -1;
        //OnCommentDelete(EventArgs.Empty);

        // Send rejection email
        EmailNotification(2);
    }




    public static Comment MakeNew(int parentNodeId, string name, string email, string website, bool approved, bool spam, DateTime created, string commentText, int statusId)
    {

        var c = new Comment
            {
                ParentNodeId = parentNodeId,
                Name = name,
                Email = email,
                Website = website,
                Approved = approved,
                Spam = spam,
                Created = created,
                CommenText = commentText,
                StatusId = statusId
            };

        var sqlHelper = DataLayerHelper.CreateSqlHelper(cms.GlobalSettings.DbDSN);

        c.Id = sqlHelper.ExecuteScalar<int>(
            @"insert into Comment(mainid,nodeid,name,email,website,comment,approved,spam,created,statusid) 
                values(@mainid,@nodeid,@name,@email,@website,@comment,@approved,@spam,@created,@statusid)",
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@mainid", -1),
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@nodeid", c.ParentNodeId),
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@name", c.Name),
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@email", c.Email),
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@website", c.Website),
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@comment", c.CommenText),
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@approved", c.Approved),
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@spam", c.Spam),
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@created", c.Created),
            sqlHelper.CreateParameter("@statusid", c.StatusId));

        c.OnCommentCreated(EventArgs.Empty);

        if (c.Spam)
        {
            c.OnCommentSpam(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        if (c.Approved)
        {
            c.OnCommentApproved(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        return c;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return @"ParentNodeId " + ParentNodeId + @"
        Name " + Name + @"
        Email " + Email + @"
        Website " + Website + @"
        Approved " + Approved + @"
        Spam " + Spam + @"
        Created "+ Created + @"
        CommenText " + CommenText + Environment.NewLine;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Send email notification
    /// </summary>
    public void EmailNotification(int notificationType)
    {

        var uCommentAdminEmail = Config.GetUCommentSetting("uCommentAdminEmail");

        MailAddress to = null;
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(uCommentAdminEmail);
        string subject = null;
        string body = null;

        switch (notificationType)
        {
            case 1:
                // Comment approved
                to = new MailAddress("me@mydomain.com");
                subject = "Comment approved";
                body = @"The comment you posted has been approved";
                break;
            case 2:
                // Comment rejected
                to = new MailAddress("me@mydomain.com");
                subject = "Comment rejected";
                body = @"The comment you posted has been rejected";
                break;
        }

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = body;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();           

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in EmailNotification: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            //
        }


    }


}
}
```

Thanks for any pointers folks!

Comment: On a different note, the SqlDataReader returned from sqlHelper.ExecuteReader call should be in a using block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a public method, but because it's not declared as static (`public static void EmailNotification`...), it cannot be used without creating an instance of the class that it lives in.

```
using System;

namespace UComment.Domain
{
    public class MyOtherClass
    {
         public void MyMethod()
         {
             Comment c = new Comment();
             c.EmailNotification(1);
         }
    }
}
```

You could declare the method static which would let you call it like this:

```
using System;

namespace UComment.Domain
{
    public class MyOtherClass
    {
         public void MyMethod()
         {
             Comment.EmailNotification(1);
         }
    }
}
```

If you're trying to use it from a different namespace then you would need to include the namespace either by a using statement or by specifying the full namespace inline.

```
using System;
using UComment.Domain;

namespace UComment.OtherNamespace
{
    public class MyOtherClass
    {
         public void MyMethod()
         {
             Comment c = new Comment();
             c.EmailNotification(1);
         }
    }
}
```

Or

```
using System;

namespace UComment.OtherNamespace
{
    public class MyOtherClass
    {
         public void MyMethod()
         {
             UComment.Domain.Comment c = new UComment.Domain.Comment();
             c.EmailNotification(1);
         }
    }
}
```

You are correct in thinking that if you wish to make this a common method, it should independent of the Comment class. The same limitations that I've just described apply to doing that. In addition, you'll have to make sure that any appropriate using statements are on the new class and that the dependencies within the EmailNotification are accounted for as well.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. When I make the EmailNotification method 'static' I always just get an error saying "Method must have a return type". It doesn't return anything though, so I'm confused what to do here?

Comment: If you're not returning anything, the return type should be void i.e., `public static void EmailNotification(`... Static is a keyword that specifies a behavior, so it's in addition to not instead of the return type.

Comment: Realized I'd missed the word void in typing part of my answer and fixed that. Sorry the typo was confusing. Fingers don't keep up with the brain once in a while.

Comment: Something has clicked!  Thank you, that makes a little bit of sense :)

Answer (score 3):

You can:

1. Extract it to a static method on static class
2. Create a singleton class that has an instance method
3. Create a class and interface for MessageSender and use DI to inject it where it's needed.

It depends on the size of the project: for small ones 1. may be enough, for big and complex (and if you have DI in place) 3 would be required.

Answer (score 2):

Your class makes too many things!

Split it in different types, each one has to solve only one type of problem according to [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Same thing for the email sending, create an EmailSender class (or another name) and centralize the Send method there.

You can also create an interface (e.g. `ISmtpClientFactory`) to pass to the EmailSender class to abstract the concrete system to send emails and improve the testing experience.

Only on the production environment you really send emails, in the test environment you can use a fake factory to simulate the sending.

```
public class EmailSender
{
    private readonly ISmtpClientFactory factory;

    public EmailSender(ISmtpClientFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void Send(MailMessage message)
    {
        using (var client = factory.Create())
        {
            using (message)
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
        }
    }
}

new EmailSender(new SmtpClientFactory()).Send(AdviceMessageFactory.Create(...));
```

Comment: I completely take your point Matteo.  I just really think I need to try to grasp the basics of what's going on though before re-factoring this - I just don't have the skills.  Maybe if the original code was better structured I'd stand more chance of understanding it and it would be better to learn from, but I'm kind of stuck with what I have.  Thanks though, I do think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in it's own class (like you already tried) and make the method static.

If this new class was EmailHelper, you would call the method like so:

```
EmailHelper.EmailNotification(1);
```

Depending on the namespace of the new class, you may also need a using statement at the top of every file you use it in.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this.  I've cut the 'EmailNotification' method out and pasted it into a new class, like this `public class EmailHelper {   ...method in here... }`.  However, now all of the references to the EmailNotification method error ("The name 'EmailNotification' does not exist in the current context").  I've tried changing those references to EmailHelper.EmailNotification(1) but this errors too ("An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'UComment.Domain.EmailHelper.EmailNotification(int)").

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like It should cause any issue If you create a (public) class and have that method in it. That method should accept all the properties it needs to send an email. You can create an instance of that class and call that method.